# Creating loop to count the number of unique values in column based on values in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

So, for example, I have the following dataframe, data:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 11 |

Now, I want to make a new column, col3, which gives me the number of unique values in col2 for every grouping in col1.

So far, I have the following code:

```
length(unique(data$col2[data$col1 == 1]))
```

Which would here return the number 2.

However, I'm having a hard time making a loop that goes through all the values in col1 to create the new column, col3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `n_distinct` after grouping

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
   group_by(col1) %>%
   mutate(col3 = n_distinct(col2)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
data
# A tibble: 6 × 3
   col1  col2  col3
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5     2
2     1     5     2
3     1     3     2
4     2    10     2
5     2    11     2
6     3    11     1
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, col3 := uniqueN(col2), col1]
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), col2 = c(5L, 
5L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the counts for every row, so using a `for` loop you would do

```
data$col3 <- NA_real_
for (i in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
  data$col3[i] <- length(unique(data$col2[data$col1 == data$col1[i]]))
}
data
#   col1 col2 col3
# 1    1    5    2
# 2    1    5    2
# 3    1    3    2
# 4    2   10    2
# 5    2   11    2
# 6    3   11    1
```

However, using `for` loops in R is mostly inefficient, and in this case we can use the grouping function `ave` which comes with R.

```
data <- transform(data, col3=ave(col2, col1, FUN=\(x) length(unique(x))))
data
#   col1 col2 col3
# 1    1    5    2
# 2    1    5    2
# 3    1    3    2
# 4    2   10    2
# 5    2   11    2
# 6    3   11    1
```

---

*Data:*

```
data <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), col2 = c(5L, 
5L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```